# Slicing Possible Empty List Python

Tags: python, list, error-handling, slice

I'm finding any overlapping elements of two lists, if any exist, and convert it to an integer.

```
list_converter = intersection[0]
```

It returns a list with only one or no values. If no value, I get:

```
    list_converter = intersection[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there a better way to do this, or to avoid the error when no the list is empty?

Comment: what do you want it to return when the list is empty? please post the input & expected output.

Comment: Just so it doesn't cause an error. I'm fine with it returning nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
if intersection:
    list_converter = intersection[0]
else:
    print "No intersection" # Or whatever you want to do if there isn't an intersection
```

In python, empty lists (i.e. `[]`) evaluate to `False` and so an empty list can be checked for using its truth value.

Answer (score 0):

```
list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
```

Comment: Would doing this fix the IndexError? Please give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the list with an if statement:

```
if len(intersection) > 0:
    list_converter = intersection[0]
else:
    print "List is empty!"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain an empty list when `intersection` is empty, you could use:

```
list_converter = intersection[0:1]
```

as no error is raised when the end of the slice is beyond the end of the list:

```
l = [1, 2 ,3]
l[0:1]
# [1]

l = []
l[0:1]
#[]
```

If you want something else, use a `try / except` block:

```
try:
    list_converter = intersection[0]
except IndexError:
    list_converter = whatever you want
```